# Find next in vimperator?

Tags: search, find, vimperator

I'm new to vimperator. Like it for the most part, but a major problem for me is the inability to find next/previous using n and N. After I do /search_term, pressing n or N only adds to the search term instead of going to the next or previous match. Is there something simple I'm missing? 
Firefox 34.0.5, vimperator 3.9, Vista 32-bit here.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: I just needed to press Enter after /search_term. Thanks to alcazoid on the IRC.